# Find position of a control relative to another control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, position

Let's say I have a custom `UserControl`. It contains a `TableLayoutPanel` with `Dock` property set to `Fill`. The `TableLayoutPanel` has a 3 rows and 2 columns. In the cell (0,1) I have a `Panel` (`Margin` 3) with a `TextBox` (`Margin` 3) inside it. How can I get the bounds of the `TextBox` relative to the `UserControl`? Measuring it by hand it should be something like X=3 and Y=29, with Width=TextBox.Width and Height=TextBox.Height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
var c = textBox1;
var p1 = c.Parent.PointToScreen(c.Location);
var p2 = this.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
var p = new Point(p1.X - p2.X, p1.Y - p2.Y);
var bounds = new Rectangle(p, c.Size);
```

I suppose this code is executing in `UserControl1`, then `bounds` is what you are looking for.

In above code `p1` is screen location of `textBox1` and `p2` is screen location of the first point of top container (`UserControl1`). So the difference between these points is the relative location of `textBox1`. Then since the size is not relative then bounds would be `new Rectangle(p, c.Size);`.

The code will work with any hierarchy regardless of depth.

Comment: The code is executing inside the UserControl, yes. But I don't need the location, I'm looking for the bounds.

Comment: Bound is new `Rectangle(Location, Size)`. Since the size is not relative so I calculated the Location :)

Comment: I added bounds too ;)